# Why can I only allocate 2 GB on a 4 GB virtual memory space?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, windows-10

My professor said that regularly, we can only use about 2 GB out of 4 GB RAM because the other 2 GB is used by the OS. However, when running some tests, I see that with a 4 GB virtual memory space of a process, I can only allocate a maximum of just under 2 GB using `VirtualAlloc()` function. Why is that (I was expecting it to be about more than 3 GB)?

As I know, the stack, data, and code segments only use a small amount of memory. One of my friend told me that the other 2 GB is used by OS just like the professor said. However, I think that the professor meant 2 GB of `physical memory`. It's not in the `virtual memory` of this process. 
Could anyone explain what happens here? Thanks.

**Some information:**

Physical memory: 4GB.

Virtual memory: 4GB.

OS: Windows 10.

Comment: You can get to about 3GB by changing how Windows boots have a read of https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/03/23/memory-management-demystifying-3gb/

Comment: Are you using 64-bit OS & compiler ?

Comment: @M.M I use 64-bit OS and compile in 32-bit.

Comment: @Rickie OK. Using more than 2^31 bytes is problematic in C and C++ with 32-bit pointers, as doing pointer subtraction with a greater span than that will cause undefined behaviour ; any functions that work on memory blocks may have unexpected failure even if you could get the allocation done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your professor is correct - 2 GB of your **virtual** memory are kernel memory.
This way, when a context switch occurs, these 2 GB can stay and only the other 2 need to be swapped. It helps performance.

You can also see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces) an explanation by Microsoft, including explanations how to increase the user portion to 3 GB.

By the way, the situation is different in 64-bit machines, where the virtual memory is much larger.

Answer (score 3):

It does not have anything to do with RAM, the *virtual* in VirtualAlloc() tells no lies.  Sure, the upper 2GB is reserved to the OS, biggest chunks it needs are the file system cache and the video memory aperture.  The latter is the bigger reason why the /3GB boot option no longer works.  As you found out, you can never get the full 2GB, your program needs address space as well and is always first.  It got it when it was loaded by the OS loader, what is left can be divvied up by VirtualAlloc.

Usually well less than 2 GB, the address space tends to get fragmented by loaded DLLs.  Beware that you might use some even if you did not link their import libraries, anti-malware and cloud-storage utilities may inject them.  Any heap allocations in your program also tends to cause splits.

These concerns are getting pretty dated, all modern machines boot a 64-bit OS.  A 32-bit program now runs in an emulator and the upper range is no longer needed by the OS.  You can now get at lot closer to 4GB by linking with the [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z(v=vs.110).aspx).  That option by itself gives you a pretty good hint why they originally decided that splitting up the address space like that was considered a good idea.  Also the approach taken in 64-bit OSes.